# Differential equation $y'' +2y' +y = e^{-x}+e^x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm learning DE and trying to solve the following equation:

> $y'' +2y' +y = e^{-x}+e^x$

I'm not really sure how to use the variation of parameters, so I decided to use the particulate solution method.

I first calculated $x^2+2x+1=0$, which equals $x_{1,2}=-1$.

Then my book suggested to replace it in form of:

$(a_0x^2e^{-x})''+2(a_0x^2e^{-x})'+a_0x^2e^{-x}=e^{-x}$

and

$(a_0e^{x})''+2(a_0e^{x})'+a_0e^{x}=e^{x}$

However, I am not sure about the $x^2$. Could someone please explain why did we put $x^2$ in the first equation?

Comment: “Particular,” not “particulate.” Gotta love auto-correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$y'' +2y' +y = e^{-x}+e^x$$
Rewrite it as :
$$(e^xy)''=1+e^{2x}$$
Integrate twice.

---

With undetermined coefficients method the guess should be:
$$y=Ae^x+Bx^2e^{-x}$$
Since $e^{-x}$ and $xe^{-x}$ are already solution to the homogeneous equation.

Answer (score 1):

Because $e^{-x}$ and $xe^{-x}$ are already solutions of the homogeneous part. So if you were to take $ae^{-x}+bxe^{-x}$, what you get is a solution of the homogeneous part, and you can never get $e^{-x}$. In those situations, what works is "going up one degree"; that's why you try with $ax^2e^{-x}$ to obtain the part with $e^{-x}$.